# Check if username exists using PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

How do I check if a username exists using PDO? All I need to know is a bool true (exists) or false (does not). I have the initial parts set up but am unsure what to do next

```
$sthandler = $dbhandler->prepare('SELECT username FROM userdb WHERE username=? LIMIT 1');
$sthandler->execute(array('username'));
// ... What's next?
```

Comment: You are gonna want to count the amount of rows that come up from the query (check tom's answer). If it's 0 the user doesn't exist, if it's 1 or more he does. One tip: I usually don't limit the query, If the username were to exist more then once I can throw an error, this means that something is bugged or a possible intruder duplicated the account...

Comment: @s4uadmin - You have to enforce certain amount of data integrity right in the database, e.g. with a unique index. Otherwise you'll get crazy testing for all the possibilities of corrupted data.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check for the row count:

```
if ( $sthandler->rowCount() > 0 ) {
  // do something here
}
```

Comment: Thanks, man. Just what I needed. Final code: `if(!$sthandler->rowCount()) throw new invalidUserException();`

Comment: i have a question please enlighten me for example no record exist count will be `0` `0` not greater than `0` so nothing will happend should it be `$sthandler->rowCount() < 1` so when a user exist it will not do anything to avoid duplicate and if none exist it will proceed?

Answer (score 2):

Just grab the row:

```
if( $row = $sthandler->fetch() ){
    // User exists: read its details here
}else{
    // User does not exist
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$username_exists = (bool) $sthandler->fetchColumn();
```

Note that you can even optimize the query a tiny bit since actually you don't need to select the username.

```
SELECT username FROM userdb ...
```

becomes

```
SELECT 1 FROM userdb ...
```