# check mysql db before inserting values using pdo in php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
$pdo = Database::connect();
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sql = "INSERT INTO cinema (name, genre, year, oscar, watched) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)";
$q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($name, $genre, $year, $oscar, $seen));
Database::disconnect();
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: @kingkero Maybe it's an easter egg, you have to find it :D

Comment: @Rizier123 Which is coming up soon, *woohoo!* Hop hop

Comment: *"check mysql db before inserting values using pdo in php"* - Query before to see if it exists. Oh, and *check FOR what?*.

Comment: @Rizier123 Mhm .. I am quite certain the table is badly configured (eg missing `UNQIUE` constraints), but the question is, what should happen after the table is queried before the `INSERT`. Either give an error (so the first query is useless anyway) or do an `UPDATE` (which has been asked&answered a ton of times as well)

Comment: hhhh
ok sorry
my question is that I want to check db table if the name and year exist 
if exist echo"already in db" else the code jump to insertion part
that's my question

Comment: Well, you can't use `rowCount()` on SELECT, so that's out. You'll need to use `count()`. Why the @#$& did they not let PDO use `rowCount()` for stuff like that, I'll never know. *Giving my head a shake.*

Comment: Apparently, in some cases you can. `if ( $sthandler->rowCount() > 0 )` check http://stackoverflow.com/q/8315835/ - http://stackoverflow.com/q/23305300/ try that and see. But the manual http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php states *PDOStatement::rowCount() returns the number of rows affected by a DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement.*

Comment: You have an answer given below. However, as @kingkero said, using a unique constraint is your best bet. You just need to code accordingly with the error handling.

Comment: $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS c FROM cinema WHERE name = ? AND year = ?";
$qq = $pdo->prepare($query);
i did this so what can i do after those lines

Answer (score 0):

Just do another query before you do the INSERT:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as c FROM cinema WHERE name = ? and year = ?
```

Do the usual prepare/bind/fetch stuff and `if ($row['c'] > 0)`  then you output your error message - otherwise you continue to your `INSERT`.

Comment: can you plz share the prepare/bind/fetch stuff